# Learning to sing with scales and vowels

Tags: voice, learning, exercises

I've started learning how to sing this week and been wondering about few things:

- Should you do triads, scales, huffing ( basically all exercises ) for all vowels?
- When attempting to sing from Diaphragm, should you sing as loud as possible? (since I live in a crowded place and it's not appreciated when I start yelling like a psycho...)
- When starting a scale, does it depend on what style you want to sing when choosing how deep/high to start or always at the lowest possible?

Also, any tips for greenies would be deeply appreciated.

P.S. Sorry for the weird definition of questions, not sure how else to ask.

Best regards,
McBooley

Answer (score 1):

> Should you do triads, scales, huffing ( basically all exercises ) for all vowels?

Yes. Especially for notes in your upper range.

> When attempting to sing from Diaphragm, should you sing as loud as possible? ( since I live in a crowded place and it's not appreciated when I start yelling like a psycho... )

Yes. And also as quietly as possible and all points in between.

> When starting a scale, does it depend on what style you want to sing when choosing how deep/high to start or always at lowest possible?

It would depend on which part of your range you want to exercise. The whole range needs to work.

> Also, any tips for greenies would be deeply appreciated.

I'm a great believer in teaching oneself but a few lessons with a good singing teacher would be immensely valuable at the start.

A good all-purpose exercise for the bel canto style is to start each note pp, slowly crescendo and then decrescendo back to pp and stop, all in one breath. This is an excellent way to develop control and steadiness.

Comment: Hello, thanks for clearing things out, I started training as you described. I found a rather weird solution for the loudness as well, namely a elevation mask, people think I've gone mad, and maybe I did, but it works and I train my breathing on a new level I guess. Although, not sure if it's a good choice to train this way?

By the way, what does "pp" mean ?

Comment: No problem. pp means pianissimo. .